# Observable subscription to ngrx store not updating on state change

Tags: angular, rxjs

Observable in a view is supposed to update when a new object is added to an array in the store, but it isn't. I can see the new object in the store via the redux plugin for chrome, but a JSON pipe of the observable doesn't change.

I store an array of active timer objects in an ngrx store. In a component, I subscribe to this array so that I can add an icon to any list items that correlate to an active timer. However, whenever I create a new timer object and update state, the observable doesn't emit. I can see the state change in redux, but the value of it in a JSON pipe in the view doesn't change.

Here is the state:

```
export interface State {
    timers: IBehaviorTimer[];
}
```

And the reducer:

```
case BehaviorActions.startTimer.type: {
   return {
       ...state,
       timers: [ ...state.timers, action.startTimerObj ]
   };
}
```

Here is the component code:

```
public timers: Observable<IBehaviorTimer[]>;
constructor() {
   this.timers = this.store.select(state => state.behavior.timers);
}
```

And the template:

```
<ion-list *ngIf="(timers | async) as timers">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let timer of timers">
    <ion-label>{{ timer.studentId }} - {{ timer.start }}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

EXPECTED: Whenever a timer is added to the store array, the component should update and show the new timer in the ion-list (not the end functionality, but can't even get this to work)

ACTUAL: Nothing happens at all. Even when I pipe it to JSON, I just get an empty array which is the initialState for the timers store array. But I can see the store get updated and contain the proper values via redux.

I know I'm missing something here, but can't for the life of me figure out what.

Comment: Did you try creating a new array instead of pushing inside the existing one?

Comment: It is my understanding that this is what returning an object using the spread operator does. Returns a new object that is created from a copy of another. e.g. state2 = { ...state } would be a copy of state, not a reference to state.

Comment: Yes its supposed to be the same but I would try it just to make sure the object's reference changes

Comment: Changed it to
```
case BehaviorActions.startTimer.type: {
    const timers = state.timers ? state.timers : [];
    return {
        ...state,
        timers: [ ...timers, action.startTimerObj ]
    };
}
```
And now it's working. Any ideas why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

So I can mark it as an answer and accept it and let the answer have more exposure than it would get in a comment, I'm going to reference ukn's comment above.
[link to the comment to my question that answered it for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198206/observable-subscription-to-ngrx-store-not-updating-on-state-change?noredirect=1#comment100923239_57198206)

> Did you try creating a new array instead of pushing inside the existing one?

Changed my reducer to:

```
case BehaviorActions.startTimer.type: {
    const timers = state.timers ? state.timers : [];
    return {
        ...state,
        timers: [ ...timers, action.startTimerObj ]
    };
}
```

store select and subscribe functions perfectly now.